# Awkward spacing when setting multiple columns using setColumnDefs() in ag-grid in Angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

***I have the following Angular ag-grid code...***

```
qrymonapp.controller("bqQueryReportController",  function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $http){
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        suppressMovableColumns:true,
        enableColResize: true,
        rowHeight : 27,
        tooltipField : true,
        suppressLoadingOverlay : true,
    }

    $http.get("url").then(function (response) {
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([{headerName: "stone1", field: "stone"}, {headerName: "stone2", field: "stone2"}])
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData([{stone: "garnett"},{stone2: "pearl"}}])
    });
});
```

***Here is my html...***

```
<div class="query-report-ag-grid">
  <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

***Here is what my grid looks like...***

[image]

Notice the weird blank space? I need the grid to have no fillers/whitespace. How do I do this?

Comment: What weird blank space?  If you are talking about the blank column values that's because you have two items in your data array and they only have a value for one column each.  Does this give what you want?  `$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData([{stone: "garnett", stone2: "pearl"}])`

Comment: @DustinHodges Yes! Thanks so much. That is exactly what I was looking for. Please put it below and an answer and I will give you the upvote. Thanks again!

Comment: I added an answer.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you are setting your data.  The data you are giving to the grid is (formatted for clarity)

```
[
  {
    stone: "garnett"
  },
  {
    stone2: "pearl"
  }
]
```

This is an array of two objects which is why you are seeing two rows.  Each object only has one key that matches a column definition so only one cell will be filled.  In order for a row to display a value in each column you need to define an object that has keys that match all the column definitions.

In this case

```
[
  {
    stone: "garnett",
    stone2: "pearl"
  }
]
```

or just `[{stone: "garnett",stone2: "pearl"}]`